# What is the right way to use ngbTooltip in ASP.NET Core 2 Angular 5 Template?

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core-2.0, ng-bootstrap

What is the right/best way to use `ngbTooltip` in ASP.NET Core 2 Angular 5  Template.

I've running ASP.NET Core 2 Angular 5 Template on following versions:

- npm 5.8.0
- node 6.9.4
- Angular CLI 1.7.4

**Scenario**

I've created my project on ASP.Net Core 2 using Angular 5 template for implement `ngbTooltip` in my components. I follow these instructions, as describe [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started).

My project is running fine but `ngbTooltip` is not showing on my HTML anchor elements. Also there is no such error is prompting in my browser console window. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong in my code.

**app.module.browser.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppModuleShared } from './app.module.shared';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        AppModuleShared
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}

export function getBaseUrl() {
    return document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
}
```

**app.module.shared.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        NgbModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {}
```

**navmenu.component.html**

```
<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
    <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/home']" placement="right" ngbTooltip="Home">
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span> Home
        </a>
    </li>
    <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/counter']" placement="right" ngbTooltip="Counter">
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-education'></span> Counter
        </a>
    </li>
    <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/fetch-data']" placement="right" ngbTooltip="Counter">
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-th-list'></span> Fetch data
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**webpack.config.vendor.js**

Also I've also add `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` entry in `treeShakableModules`

```
const treeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/animations',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap',
    'zone.js'
];
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'bootstrap',
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    'es6-promise',
    'es6-shim',
    'event-source-polyfill',
    'jquery',
];
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "site2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.2",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.8.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
   "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3"
  }
}
```

**Output**

when I hover on any anchor tag there is no such tooltip shown. Kindly help me on this what I'm doing wrong in my code. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using any other ng-bootstrap component ? Do they work ?

Comment: Also, if you are using AOT you should also import it in app.module.server.ts

Comment: What I need to import in app.module.server.ts file?

Comment: Yes I've using AOT and I have implement it in boot.browser.ts

Comment: `const modulePromise = platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);`

Comment: You only imported `NgbModule.forRoot()` in app.module.browser.ts. Import in in app.module.server.ts also

Comment: @CornelC also not working when I imported `NgbModule.forRoot()` in app.module.server.ts